# Decode a chrome app or extension

Tags: google-chrome, decode

I found a chrome app for photography effects which works offline perfectly. But it is having limited features. I have some ideas to add for my use. But I'll require to develop complete app. That'll take more time.

Is there any way so I can modify the app for my personal use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well!! I got to know that all chrome extensions/apps are made in HTML & JS. So I can easily decode them by using some chrome crx file downloader or directly from its extension folder.